# Pivot table - apply date filter to pivotField.currentPage

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to apply a String, Date and Time filter to 3 page fields on top of a pivot table. String filter applies succesfully, but Date and Time filters give me an "Application-defined or object-defined error".

This is the code i'm using:

```
Private Sub filterPivot_Rebid(budgetFilter, dateFilter, timeFilter)
    On Error GoTo endError
    
    Dim PT As PivotTable, PF As PivotField
    Set PT = WS_Deliverables_Rebid.PivotTables("PivRebid")
    
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    With PT
        Set PF = .PivotFields("Budget Type")
        PF.ClearAllFilters
        PF.CurrentPage = budgetFilter 'Value is BID 03 and it applies succesfully
        
        Set PF = .PivotFields("Date")
        PF.ClearAllFilters
        PF.CurrentPage = dateFilter   'Value is 06-Aug-2020, and it returns the error. I tried cDate, and format to m/d/yyyy, same result
        
        Set PF = .PivotFields("Time")
        PF.ClearAllFilters
        PF.CurrentPage = timeFilter    'Value is 13:01:58, and it returns the error

'THIS IS THE RECORDED VERSION
''            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivRebid").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = _
''        "8/6/2020"
''    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivRebid").PivotFields("Time").ClearAllFilters
''    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivRebid").PivotFields("Time").CurrentPage = _
''        "12:28:28 PM"
    End With
    'PT.PivotCache.Refresh
    
done:
Exit Sub

endError:
    RaiseError Err, "filterPivot_Rebid (" & budgetFilter & ", " & dateFilter & ", " & timeFilter & ")", Erl
End Sub
```

How can I apply the page fields correctly?

Comment: Please, appropriately declare the variables `budgetFilter, dateFilter, timeFilter`. Otherwise, they are all of `Variant Type`...

Comment: Could you try PF.CurrentPageName = dateFilter ?